# Specflow - Could we pass parameters in the Specflow Example Table

Tags: c#, api, automation, bdd, specflow

My scenario is

```
Scenario Outline: Verify if the user can create an response if user posts a request with invalid payload
    Given User had specified name <name> description <description> in create application request
    And User had specified tenantId id <tenantId> in header of createApplication request
    When User sends a create request to application service with invalidPayload
    Then User should get an error code <errorCode> in the createApplication response with error message as <errorMessage>
Examples:
| description| name | errorCode | errorMessage|tenantid|                                                            
| testdescription| DummyApplication| 857 | Application named ${name} already exists for a given tenant | mock|
```

In the above section i want to validate the error message but with the name parameter , value for which is defined already in the example table.
My expected error message to be passed as parameter is,
"Application named 'DummyApplication' already exists for a given tenant."

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach would be to store the variable when you have it and re-use it when you later need it.  You could use ScenarioContext and have a property for example.

```
 private string Name
 {
   get
   {
      return ScenarioContext.Current["Name"].ToString();
   }
   set
   {
      ScenarioContext.Current["Name"] = value;
   }
        }

[Given(@"User had specified name (.*) description (.*) in create application request")]
        public void GivenUserHadSpecifiedNameDummyApplicationDescriptionTestdescriptionInCreateApplicationRequest(string name, string description)
        {
            // store the name
            this.Name = name;
        }


        [Then(@"User should get an error code (.*) in the createApplication response with error message as (.*)")]
        public void ThenUserShouldGetAnErrorCodeInTheCreateApplicationResponseWithErrorMessageAsApplicationNamedNameAlreadyExistsForAGivenTenant(int errorCode, string errorMessage)
        {
            // retrieve the name and use
            var expected = errorMessage.Replace("${name}", $"'{this.Name}'");
            //Application named 'DummyApplication' already exists for a given tenant

        }
```

Comment: In the current specflow example table
`| description| name | errorCode | errorMessage|tenantid|
| testdescription| DummyApplication| 857 | Application named ${name} already exists for a given tenant | mock| `

if name parameter above changes to ApplicationName in future 

don't i need to make changes in the errormessage parameter from ${name} to ${ApplicationName}

as well in the step definition code
`var expected = errorMessage.Replace("${name}", $"'{this.Name}'");`
In the above code i need to replace ${name} by ${ApplicationName}

Comment: sorry I've just re-read this.  If you mean changing the specflow definition to |description|ApplicationName|... - in that case you wouldn't have to change anything, the specflow step expects 2 parameters - one for name, one for description.  What they're called doesn't matter.   $(name) in the specflow errror messages examples is just a placeholder, which gets replaced.